# Evaluate a model for a changing distribution

Tags: predictive-models

Suppose that I have an unfair 6-sided die. Each time I roll it, the weights for the various sides change in a deterministic way (edit: based on the result**s of all previous rolls**). (Perhaps the weights are always 10%, 10%, 10%, 10%, 10%, 50%, but which face has a 50% chance of showing changes after each roll. But I am interested in the more general case.)

If I have a model for how I think the weights change and a large number of trials, how do I evaluate my model?

In other words, I have rolled the die a large number $N$ of times, and before the $j$th trial my model computes probabilities $p_{j,1}, \dots, p_{j,6}$ corresponding to the six faces. What tools can I use to evaluate my model?

(I hope you'll feel free to change tags, title, etc. I am new here.)

[**edit:** I lack reputation to post comments. I need a goodness-of-fit test. It is not clear to me how to apply the usual chi-squared test, since the samples are taken from an ever-changing distribution.]

[**edit 2:** Thank you for your patience. Maybe we should start by ignoring the procedural aspect of the setup. So suppose I have $N \approx 1000$ unfair 6-sided dice, and for each one I have a hypothesis about what distribution its rolls follow. I roll all the dice once (so I have only one sample) and record the results. **Is there some statistical tool I can use to evaluate my hypothesis based on this sample?**

For example, if I hypothesize that the even-numbered dice should all favor 6 but I roll mostly 1s in the even-numbered dice, then perhaps I should reject my hypothesis. With more confidence as $N$ increases.

The usual chi-squared tests do not seem to apply, since I am not sampling many times from the same distribution. But maybe I am missing something.]

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Cross Validated! See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/598267/56940) for an answer, with minor adaptation, to your quest.

Comment: This is a Markov Chain.  It's unclear, though, what you mean by "evaluating" your model.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: You do not lack reputation to post comments: you have two different accounts.  Visit https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to merge them so you can edit and comment on your post.  It remains unclear how a GoF test might possibly be related to this question, so please elaborate on that.

Comment: thank you both for your comments and patience. I do care about the case where the distribution changes depending on the entire history of rolls (which I did not state clearly in the original statement of the question), so I don't think this is a Markov chain in any sense that I'm familiar with. I have made an edit that includes (what I hope to be) a clearer question.

Comment: Which of the following sequences of 20 rolls is more likely? $$2 4 1 1 4 5 3 4 5 3 6 2 2 2 1 5 3 3 4 5$$ or $$1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1$$ I guess that they are equally likely. Unless you have some ideas about the ways that the fairness of the die can change, a sequence doesn't tell anything about fairness of the die.

Comment: OK, it is clear that in an effort to make things simpler I have made them worse. So I asked a new question, hopefully clearer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/601674/testing-a-hypothesis-about-playlist-shuffling

Comment: (admins feel free to close this one)