# Testing a hypothesis about playlist-shuffling

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have a piece of closed-source software that plays music. I am trying to determine how it shuffles a playlist. Standard empirical tests suggest that it does *not* simply choose one of the $n$ songs uniformly at random each time; it uses some method to reduce repetitions.

I hypothesize that the software uses the following method. Each song in the playlist has some number of tickets. After playing a song, the software sets that song's number of tickets to 0 (so that the song will not be repeated immediately) and gives one additional ticket to every song that was not played. (Notice that the total number of tickets varies over time.) Then the software draws a ticket uniformly at random and plays the song that owns that ticket.

**What statistical tests are available to me to test my hypothesis, assuming that I can run the software on, say, a 10-song playlist for a very long time?**

P.S. This is off-topic, but I would be interested to know how standard software actually shuffles playlists, if anyone knows. :)

Comment: There might be no current test (in the sense that it's not explicitly listed in a book or paper, which is what it sounds like you mean) for that specific hypothesis, but it's a fairly trivial matter to construct one. To that end, (assuming your want your hypothesis as a null case), what sorts of alternatives did you want to have power against?

Comment: OK. Well, certainly the claim that the songs are chosen uniformly and independently at random, but that can already be ruled out. An alternative theory would be that the software lists the n songs in order of how recently they've been played and uses some fixed weights p_1,...,p_n to determine the probability that the kth-most-recent song will be chosen.

Comment: I could try to think of other alternatives, but I imagine they would be less plausible. This is a system designed by humans, after all.